# Loop inside a loop with lapply

Tags: r, lapply

I have to factor levels in my data.
Rather than doing repetitive coding for every of these levels I want to loop through them at once.

I don't get want I am doing wrong but the result is an empty list:

```
lapply(levels(DF$fct1), function(y)
lapply(levels(DF$fct2), function(x)
  qqPlot(droplevels(na.omit(DF[DF$fct1==y & DF$fct2==x,c("fct1","isotopic_value","fct2")]))$isotopic_value)
  ))
```

I guess it is my syntax.

Comment: Could you maybe share your data using `dput(DF)`?

Comment: Not sure ... but you can get an equivalent effect (albeit a 1-deep list vice this 2-deep list) with `lapply(split(DF, DF[,c("fct1", "fct2")]), function(dat) qqPlot(droplevels(dat$isotopic_value)))`.

Comment: Thank you r2evans - this solution worked very nicely